# Unable to run latest react-native app on android

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I have created a fresh app from react-native-cli.

The generated boilerplate had the following versions.

**React-native**: *0.57.8*

**React**: *16.6.3*

**Gradle Version**: *4.4*

**Java Version (JDK)**: *1.8.0_191-b12*

I am unable to execute `react-native run-android`

I get the following error

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Could not generate a proxy class for class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.BuildArtifactReportTask.

I want to know whether the error is due to react version or gradlew

**P.S.** Application builds and installs on device / emulator when running through Android Studio but not when running via `react-native-cli`

Comment: For sure the problem related to JDK version or installation. Try download it again and remove your grade and make it gain. Then 'killall node' on the terminal and delete the app on your simulator or cellphone and try to run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Please update the JDK version after that go to the inside android folder and use this cmd

```
./gradlew clean
```

after cleaning gradle try to build again.

Comment: I solved it by updating my JAVA_HOME variable with latest jdk folder.

Comment: yeah the problem was about the JDK version.